# SSRS and Excel color compatibility

Tags: excel, reporting-services, colors

I have SSRS Reports created and rendering in Excel format. I used a custom color(mentioned in excel spec R23, G123, B87) in SSRS. But it shows a different color with the same combination in SSRS. And once I render the report to Excel it shows the color different though I used the same color combination.

Why the color difference in Excel and SSRS? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

The standard Microsoft Excel 2003 color palette has 40 colors plus 16 colors for chart fills and lines.  Most of the current builds of Business Intelligence reporting systems (Cognos Series 8, Business Objects XI R3, Reporting Services 2000/2005, etc.) automatically translate colors to the "closest matching" Excel 2003 color palette selection as part of the render to Excel method.  This can be very frustrating for Office 2007 users given that Excel has virtually unlimited color palette choices by default.

Reporting Services 2008 DOES NOT have this color palette restriction.  If you render a report to Excel in Reporting Services 2008, then the colors will match the colors that are displayed in your HTML rendered report.

Comment: Is there anything we can do changing the rendering properties for excel format in the Render Engine side?

Comment: It's also important to note that RS 2008 changes the excel default color palette to include the needed colors for the rendered report.  This can cause issues when combining multiple excel reports into one as they will all share the same color palette.  If the reports use different colors or even the same colors in a different order, then the colors on the merged reports will be off.  They seem to use an index to find the color in the palette, so this gets very tricky if you need to merge two excel rendered reports.

Comment: That's good to know.  I've never encountered this problem before that I noticed, but I will keep my eyes open for it in the future.

Comment: Here is a great article about the Excel Palette with visuals for anyone else who would like to understand it more. http://answers.officewriter.com/excels-color-palette-explained